# Displaying Events - Display only 5 coming up next

Tags: jquery, ajax

Well folks I am still working on getting Google Calendar Events listed at the bottom of my website but having no luck. When I first started this project with an objective for listing the 5 most recent upcoming events in chronological order by date. My calendar does contains one event that happens every Tuesday night, if the next 5 events being displayed are the same then thats fine. BUT if there happens to be an event next Monday then it should also appear as one of the 5 upcoming events, again in chronological order by date. i.e. 01/01/2018, 01/04/2018 etc...

Here is the site to see how the results are coming out at the very bottom of the page. http://eaa309.club/index.html

As you can see its displaying older events where I would like to only display events in the future.

Originally someone on this forum helped me with creating the code since I know nothing about AJAX etc.. However here is what I have (Below in code block). Any help would be greatly appreciated at modifying this code to display what Im looking for.

NOTE: Im using some of the out of the box variables that can be used in the API GET method but I'm no sure if there currently working. Its almost as if its pulling data based on the results of the get method which happens to be all calendar events (no filter) and not the 5 most resent. I verified this by going to the following: URL:https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?singleEvents=true&maxResults=5&orderBy=startTime&key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4

Makes sense I do not believe there os code to filter out this type of criteria.

```
<p id="myList"></p>
            <!--JQuery CDN-->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
        //Jquery's ajax request
        $.ajax({
               type:'GET',
               url:'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaachapter309@gmail.com/events?singleEvents=true&maxResults=5&orderBy=startTime&key=AIzaSyBZilw_M3Jk14gkmGk_bBuQUcBr_EW5RI4',
               dataType: 'json',
               async:true

               }).done(function(data){
                       //once we get a successful response this callback function
                       //gets fired, and "data" contains the parsed json file .

                       //here we iterate over the object array
                       $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                              //I do this to later format these timestamps
                              //set options for date.toLocaleDateString() function

                              var options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' };

                              let start = new Date(item.start.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

                              let end = new Date(item.end.dateTime).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

                              let end_splt = end.split(',');



                              //append data to the list.


                              if(item.status != "cancelled"){
                              $('#myList').append(`
                                                  <font class='mbr-text mbr-fonts-style foot-text display-7'><a href='calendar.html'>~ ${item.summary} - ${start} - ${end_splt[1]} </a></font><br>
                                                  `);
                              }

                              });

                       }).fail(function(e){
                               error(e);
                               });

                               var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            </script>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I googled for ordering by starttime in reverse order and I can't seem to find anything on the subject... weird that it'd be so limited.

Comment: Tell me about it. If it were a DB I could could right all kinds of filters against it to get what I'm looking for. I think thats why writing additional code around it is necessary.